# CoreData: ObjectID Error: "No known class method for selector 'managedObjectContext'

Tags: ios, core-data, reference, objectid

```
@implementation FirstScene
...
- (void)nextScene {
    Meetings *meetings = (Meetings *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Meetings" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObjectID* objectID = [meetings objectID];
    [secondScene setObjectID:objectID];
}
...
@end

@implementation SecondScene
....
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.managedObjectContext = [(STAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]  delegate] managedObjectContext];
}

+ (void)setObjectID:(NSManagedObjectID*)objectID {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext]; // ERROR
    Meetings *theSameMeetings = (Meetings *)[context objectWithID:objectID];
}
...
@end
```

I'm getting an error "No known class method for selector 'managedObjectContext' in the following code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
```

My objective here is to pass the objectID of *meetings (managedObjectContext) in FirstScene to the SecondScene so that I can continue to add to the entity *meetings attributes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a Core Data error, it's a basic Objective-C error. You're in this method:

```
+ (void)setObjectID:(NSManagedObjectID*)objectID;
```

The "+" says that this is a class method, not an instance method. So `self` in this case is the `SecondScene` class, not any particular instance of that class. When you try to do this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
```

...you're trying to call a method named `+managedObjectContext`, i.e. a class method with that name. That apparently doesn't exist, which isn't too surprising.

I suspect you intended for `setObjectID:` to be an instance method, which means it should have a `-` instead of a `+` at the start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `[self managedObjectContext]` the compiler is looking for a method name in the current target that is `-(void)managedObjectContext` which clearly doesn't exist.  The best way to pass an object ID is set a property and synthesize that property, that will allow you to assign the objectID to an instance of meeting, and then retrieve it from said instance.

--EDIT--

In whichever class you need to access your ManagedObjectID you want to declare your delegate as such:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Then in your setObjectID method you can call:

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm new to this. Do I create an instance of NSManagedObjectID in FirstScene or the SecondScene?   Can you please elaborate on " that will allow you to assign the objectID to an instance of meeting, and then retrieve it from said instance."

Comment: You'll want to declare the managedObject Context in your AppDelegate, and then you need to create an instance of your app delegate in the class you need to access the managedObjectContext from.  I will edit my answer with code

Comment: Thank you for providing the code.  Question: Isn't that the samething as what I have in my code already?  I have this code in every class that needs access to managedObjectContext in viewDidLoad:  self.managedObjectContext = [(STAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]  delegate] managedObjectContext];

Comment: You are still calling [self managedObjectContext] and unless there is a method in your SecondScene class called -(void) managedObjectContext, this will call an error.  Since that method is defined in your delegate you have to call [myDelegate managedObjectContext];

Comment: In viewDidLoad in FirstScene I have:  STAppDelegate *appDelegate = (STAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Now in method where I need to save, I have the following line that's causing the error:
Meetings *meetings = (Meetings *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Meetings" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
The error that I get: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Meetings''

Comment: I should be able to access managedObjectContext through appDelegate.managedObjectContext ?  I have had this error before and I'm thinking it's because the app can't is unable to reach managedObjectContext.  When I go back to self.managedObjectContext =... code, the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Brother, as it says you do not have 'managedObjectContext' method in your 'SecondScene'. is it?

Apparently you are a beginner to core data and you have just stepped into it.

however, Go to AppDelegate of your project, and search for '-(void)managedObjectContext' and you will see that there is a manageobjectcontext method there, replace [self manageobjectcontext] with the method from AppDelegate.

This will allow you to have access to appdelegate

```
YourAppDelegateClass   *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; and now call [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

Hope this helps.